# Bootstrap dropdown. Opens on hover but how to close on click?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap dropdown which opens on hover (as desired) but I can not make it close on click. Specifically I would like the dropdown to close once a selection is made. How can I do this please? Note that the selection is reflected in the dropdown text (which is fine), but the dropdown itself remains open.

My code is attached, for some reason which I dont understand the dropdowns I am talking about, appear when you go full screen after running the code snippet below, otherwise only the `nav-bar header` is shown.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    
    <!--jquery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!--d3 -->
    <script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js'></script>

    <style>
        /*Show/hide dropdown menu on mouse hover*/
        .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
            display: block;
        }

        /*Styling on the navbar*/
        .navbar-inverse {
          background-color: #3d4a57;
          border-color: #333;
        }

        .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a,
        .navbar a.navbar-brand {
              color: #fbfbfb;
              text-decoration: none;
            }
    </style>


</head>

<body class="application" id="body">



<!-- main page container, holding the nav tabs and content -->
<div id="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Some title</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown" id="myDropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="myDropdown dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
                               aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Select Data
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick='myDropdownSelector("Dataset 1")'>Dataset 1</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick='myDropdownSelector("Dataset 2")'>Dataset 2</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick='myDropdownSelector("Dataset 3")'>Dataset 3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown" id="dropdown-inefficiency">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-valueSetter dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
                               aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Intensity Value
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick='set_value("1.0")'>1.0</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick='set_value("2.0")'>2.0</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick='set_value("3.0")'>3.0</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div><!--/.container-fluid -->

        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function myDropdownSelector(x){
            d3.select('.myDropdown').node().text = x + '  ';
            $('.myDropdown').append("<span class='caret'></span>");
        }

        function set_value(x){
            d3.select('.dropdown-valueSetter').node().text = 'Value: ' + x + '  '
            $('.dropdown-valueSetter').append("<span class='caret'></span>");
        }
    </script>


</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you could add a `onclick` listener on your body and when it's triggered check if `event.target` is different than your dropdown element. if so, close it.

Comment: check by adding  event.stopPropagation(); in your click function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a big script (`d3.v4.min.js`) to do some of the dropdown handling in JavaScript for you. Please refer to the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking a question in the future if you would like to see a more specific answer.

I tried using simple jQuery to make something work according to your requirements, result being the showing and hiding of certain dropdown:

```js
function myDropdownSelector(x) {
  d3.select('.myDropdown').node().text = x + '  ';
  $('.myDropdown').append("<span class='caret'></span>");
}

function set_value(x) {
  d3.select('.dropdown-valueSetter').node().text = 'Value: ' + x + '  '
  $('.dropdown-valueSetter').append("<span class='caret'></span>");
}

//Rather use jQuery DOM ready function to execute DOM manipulation over regular JavaScript
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".nav.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu").on("click", ".dropdown-item", function() {
   $(".dropdown-menu").hide();
  });
  $(".nav.navbar-nav .dropdown > a#foo").hover(function() {
   $(".dropdown-menu#bar").show();
  });
  $(".nav.navbar-nav .dropdown > a#alpha").hover(function() {
   $(".dropdown-menu#beta").show();
  });
});
```

```css
/* Show/hide dropdown menu on mouse hover */

.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

/* Styling on the navbar */

.navbar-inverse {
  background-color: #3d4a57;
  border-color: #333;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a,
.navbar a.navbar-brand {
  color: #fbfbfb;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div class="application" id="body">
  <!-- main page container, holding the nav tabs and content -->
  <div id="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Some title</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="dropdown" id="myDropdown">
                <a href="#" class="myDropdown dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="alpha">
                                  Select Data
                                  <span class="caret"></span>
                              </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="beta">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick='myDropdownSelector("Dataset 1")'>Dataset 1</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick='myDropdownSelector("Dataset 2")'>Dataset 2</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick='myDropdownSelector("Dataset 3")'>Dataset 3</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="dropdown" id="dropdown-inefficiency">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-valueSetter dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="foo">
                  Intensity Value
                  <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="bar">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick='set_value("1.0")'>1.0</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick='set_value("2.0")'>2.0</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick='set_value("3.0")'>3.0</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!--/.container-fluid -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2xm9h3ku/)**

The dropdowns will close once a selection has been made. This should solve your (client side) problem for as far as you have asked for.

Comment: Thanks Barrosy, thats great. I added `$(".dropdown-menu#bar").hide();` inside the hover function for `a#alpha` and a similar one for `a#foo` so that the dropdown menu hides when the other one is open. Hence at any given time only one dropdown can be open. I have also added these lines

Comment: (...Continuing from above..)  `$(".dropdown-menu#bar").mouseleave(function(){  $(".dropdown-menu#bar").hide(); });` and its equivalent for `#beta` in order to make the dropdown close on a mouseleave event. I works almost fine (when you mouse over the `navbar header` the dropdown stays open). Is this a sensible way to do that please?

Comment: It all depends on your requirements, if this is meeting your expected behaviour, then yes. If you are trying to mimick some behaviour, you should check carefully what events fire and how these events would be handled after firing. (I cannot judge without full code and desired result) You are using Bootstrap so I would recommend to stick to the code available in documentation as much as possible (for readability and reusability purpose).

Comment: I would say there is nothing wrong in using jQuery to add more dynamic to your (bootstrap) elements as long as you do not break anything. In the end that is what JavaScript (and jQuery) is meant for.

Answer (score 0):

You can close the dropdown by getting the reference of ul tag and calling hide() function on it like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset='utf-8'>

    <!--jquery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!--d3 -->
    <script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js'></script>

    <style>
        /*Show/hide dropdown menu on mouse hover*/
        .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
            display: block;
        }

        /*Styling on the navbar*/
        .navbar-inverse {
          background-color: #3d4a57;
          border-color: #333;
        }

        .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a,
        .navbar a.navbar-brand {
              color: #fbfbfb;
              text-decoration: none;
            }
    </style>


</head>

<body class="application" id="body">



<!-- main page container, holding the nav tabs and content -->
<div id="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Some title</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown" id="myDropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="myDropdown dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
                               aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Select Data
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dataset">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick='myDropdownSelector("Dataset 1")'>Dataset 1</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick='myDropdownSelector("Dataset 2")'>Dataset 2</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick='myDropdownSelector("Dataset 3")'>Dataset 3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown" id="dropdown-inefficiency">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-valueSetter dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
                               aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Intensity Value
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="value">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick='set_value("1.0")'>1.0</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick='set_value("2.0")'>2.0</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick='set_value("3.0")'>3.0</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div><!--/.container-fluid -->

        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function myDropdownSelector(x){
            d3.select('.myDropdown').node().text = x + '  ';
            $('.myDropdown').append("<span class='caret'></span>");
            $("#dataset").hide();
        }

        function set_value(x){
            d3.select('.dropdown-valueSetter').node().text = 'Value: ' + x + '  '
            $('.dropdown-valueSetter').append("<span class='caret'></span>");
            $("#value").hide();
        }
    </script>


</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Notice the functions myDropdownSelector and set_value.

Here is the working version of it in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jbeg9xq0/)

Comment: many thanks. The only issue I had with this is that once you do a selection with the dropdown then you cannot open it again. Its fine the very first time, but after that the dropdown remains closed. Mouseover of click doesnt seem to do anything. I guess tho that it is not going to be a big pain fixing that (if one knows how to do it...)